# Given a small pilot study, how to compute number of samples needed for a certain power?

Tags: sample-size, cohens-d

I ran a small pilot study and computed both a p-value and Cohen's d. Now how do I compute the number of samples needed for the full study if I want a given power (e.g. 95%).

I hoped I could use [this table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sample_size_determination#By_tables), but I can't figure out how it's calculated.

**Edit:** More details on the study: We're manipulating a single variable (condition A and B). Each participant will have N readings from each condition. The question is, how do we compute how many participants we'll need given the results of a pilot study with one participant.

Comment: Mike, please indicate what kinds of data your study will be collecting and what you are trying to compare: those things need to be known in order to compute the power.

Comment: @whuber: I put more info in the question. Let me know if more is needed. Thanks.

Comment: What comparison are you making?  What are you trying to determine?

Comment: Each participant would have a mean reading for each condition. Then I could run a t-test and determine the significance of the differences in readings between conditions. I know I shouldn't just keep running participants until I reach p<0.05. So I'm trying predetermine the number of participants needed.